# How would I convert this JSON so that I can add it to a MySQL database using Flask-SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, mysql, json, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

JSON

{"users": [{"username": "userxyz", "id": 4, "email": "xyz@gmail.com", "events": [{"event_name": "vday"}, {"event_name": "bday"}]}]}

DB

```
class User(db.Model):

    id= db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username= db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email= db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    events= db.relationship('Event', backref='user')

class Event(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    event_name = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
```

Schemas

```
class UserSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
        events = fields.Nested('EventSchema', many=True)

class Meta:
    model = User

class EventSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        exclude = ('id', 'user_id', 'user')
```

Comment: Please provide the codes you tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is this thing json.dumps(values) you can use this to dump data .this will convert your json object in a json string so that you can insert it into text field in your database.
have a look at this link [json](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html)

Answer (score 0):

First you'll want to import your json file:

```
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize


with open("json_file_path_goes_here") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

# data = {"users": [{"username": "userxyz", 
#                    "id": 4, 
#                    "email": "xyz@gmail.com", 
#                    "events": [{"event_name": "vday"}, 
#                               {"event_name": "bday"}]
#                  }]
#        }
```

You can then use [json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html) to get it in a structured format:

```
df = json_normalize(data["users"], "events", ["email", "id", "username"]).set_index('id')

#     event_name    email       username
# id            
# 4     vday    xyz@gmail.com   userxyz
# 4     bday    xyz@gmail.com   userxyz
```

From that dataframe it's a simple one liner to add entries to your database:

```
df.to_sql('User', engine, if_exists='append')
```